# PIC32 USB CDC is slow to write and raises erroneous flag

Tags: driver, pic32

I am currently attempting to write code for a pic32MZ2048EFH100 which receives and responds to messages from a custom program on a PC through the USB CDC drivers in harmony.

Currently, the pic is able to both send and receive messages. However, whenever it sends a message to the PC, it always raises the buffer 80% full flag (EV_RX80FULL) incorrectly. In addition to this, the PIC32 sends messages relatively slowly. I am porting the firmware over from a TERN board which works correctly. There are times when the PC sends two messages very quickly, the TERN will send out an acknowledgement for one, receive the next, and then acknowledge that one. The PIC, on the other hand, will receive both and then send out two acknowledgements which will cause problems with the program on the PC side.

The largest difference between the two boards is that the drivers are different which is where we think the problem is originating. The PIC uses a driver from Microchip and the .inf is as follows

```
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;Note: When the driver package is signed, any modifications to this .inf file will
;break the signature, and the driver package will need to be re-signed.
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Modified Windows USB CDC Abstract Control Model Serial Driver Setup File
; Copyright (C) 2012 Microchip Technology Inc.

[Version] 
Signature="$Windows NT$" 
Class=Ports
ClassGuid={4D36E978-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318} 
Provider=%MFGNAME% 
CatalogFile=%MFGFILENAME%.cat
DriverVer=10/06/2014,5.1.2600.9

[Manufacturer] 
%MFGNAME%=DeviceList,NTamd64


;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;  Vendor and Product ID Definitions
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; When developing your USB device, the VID and PID used in the PC side
; application program and the firmware on the microcontroller must match.
; The VID and PID can be changed in the USB device descriptor and on the below 
; lines in this file.  If you modify this .inf file to customize it for your
; device, please remove all existing Microchip (VID 0x04D8) entries from
; the device lists.
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DeviceList]
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_04D8&PID_000A
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_04D8&PID_0205
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_04D8&PID_0206
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_04D8&PID_00DF&MI_00
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_04D8&PID_0057&MI_01
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_04D8&PID_006E&MI_01
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_04D8&PID_0208&MI_00
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_04D8&PID_0208&MI_02
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_04D8&PID_00DD&MI_00
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_04D8&PID_0207&MI_00

[DeviceList.NTamd64] 
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_04D8&PID_000A
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_04D8&PID_0205
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_04D8&PID_0206
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_04D8&PID_00DF&MI_00
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_04D8&PID_0057&MI_01
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_04D8&PID_006E&MI_01
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_04D8&PID_0208&MI_00
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_04D8&PID_0208&MI_02
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_04D8&PID_00DD&MI_00
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_04D8&PID_0207&MI_00


;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;  Windows 32bit OSes Section
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DriverInstall.nt] 
include=mdmcpq.inf
CopyFiles=FakeModemCopyFileSection 
AddReg=DriverInstall.nt.AddReg 

[DriverInstall.nt.AddReg] 
HKR,,DevLoader,,*ntkern 
HKR,,NTMPDriver,,%DRIVERFILENAME%.sys 
HKR,,EnumPropPages32,,"MsPorts.dll,SerialPortPropPageProvider" 

[DriverInstall.NT.Services]
include=mdmcpq.inf 
AddService=usbser, 0x00000002, LowerFilter_Service_Inst 


;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;  Windows 64bit OSes Section
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DriverInstall.NTamd64]
include=mdmcpq.inf
CopyFiles=FakeModemCopyFileSection
AddReg=DriverInstall.NTamd64.AddReg 

[DriverInstall.NTamd64.AddReg] 
HKR,,DevLoader,,*ntkern 
HKR,,NTMPDriver,,%DRIVERFILENAME%.sys 
HKR,,EnumPropPages32,,"MsPorts.dll,SerialPortPropPageProvider" 

[DriverInstall.NTamd64.Services] 
include=mdmcpq.inf 
AddService=usbser, 0x00000002, LowerFilter_Service_Inst 


;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;  Common Sections
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DestinationDirs] 
DefaultDestDir=12 

[SourceDisksNames]

[SourceDisksFiles]

[FakeModemCopyFileSection]

[LowerFilter_Service_Inst]
DisplayName= %SERVICE%
ServiceType= 1
StartType  = 3
ErrorControl = 0
ServiceBinary = %12%\usbser.sys


;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;  String Definitions
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; These strings can be modified to customize your device
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Strings]
MFGFILENAME="mchpcdc"
DRIVERFILENAME ="usbser"
MFGNAME="Microchip Technology, Inc."   ;This name shows up in the device manager properties for the device
DESCRIPTION="USB Serial Port"          ;This is the "friendly name" that shows up in the device manager
SERVICE="USB to Serial Driver"
```

Here is the USB configuration on the PIC:

```
/**************************************************
 * USB Device Function Driver Init Data
 **************************************************/
    const USB_DEVICE_CDC_INIT cdcInit0 =
    {
        .queueSizeRead = 1,
        .queueSizeWrite = 1,
        .queueSizeSerialStateNotification = 1
    };
/**************************************************
 * USB Device Layer Function Driver Registration 
 * Table
 **************************************************/
const USB_DEVICE_FUNCTION_REGISTRATION_TABLE funcRegistrationTable[1] =
{
    /* Function 1 */
    { 
        .configurationValue = 1,    /* Configuration value */ 
        .interfaceNumber = 0,       /* First interfaceNumber of this function */ 
        .speed = USB_SPEED_HIGH|USB_SPEED_FULL,    /* Function Speed */ 
        .numberOfInterfaces = 2,    /* Number of interfaces */
        .funcDriverIndex = 0,  /* Index of CDC Function Driver */
        .driver = (void*)USB_DEVICE_CDC_FUNCTION_DRIVER,    /* USB CDC function data exposed to device layer */
        .funcDriverInit = (void*)&cdcInit0    /* Function driver init data */
    },
};

/*******************************************
 * USB Device Layer Descriptors
 *******************************************/
/*******************************************
 *  USB Device Descriptor 
 *******************************************/
const USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR deviceDescriptor =
{
    0x12,                           // Size of this descriptor in bytes
    USB_DESCRIPTOR_DEVICE,          // DEVICE descriptor type
    0x0200,                         // USB Spec Release Number in BCD format
    USB_CDC_CLASS_CODE,         // Class Code
    USB_CDC_SUBCLASS_CODE,      // Subclass code
    0x00,                       // Protocol code
    USB_DEVICE_EP0_BUFFER_SIZE,     // Max packet size for EP0, see system_config.h
    0x04D8,                         // Vendor ID
    0x000A,                         // Product ID
    0x0100,                         // Device release number in BCD format
    0x01,                           // Manufacturer string index
    0x02,                           // Product string index
    0x00,                           // Device serial number string index
    0x01                            // Number of possible configurations
};

/*******************************************
 *  USB Device Qualifier Descriptor for this
 *  demo.
 *******************************************/
const USB_DEVICE_QUALIFIER deviceQualifierDescriptor1 =
{
    0x0A,                               // Size of this descriptor in bytes
    USB_DESCRIPTOR_DEVICE_QUALIFIER,    // Device Qualifier Type
    0x0200,                             // USB Specification Release number
    USB_CDC_CLASS_CODE,         // Class Code
    USB_CDC_SUBCLASS_CODE,      // Subclass code
    0x00,                       // Protocol code
    USB_DEVICE_EP0_BUFFER_SIZE,         // Maximum packet size for endpoint 0
    0x01,                               // Number of possible configurations
    0x00                                // Reserved for future use.
};

/*******************************************
 *  USB High Speed Configuration Descriptor
 *******************************************/

const uint8_t highSpeedConfigurationDescriptor[]=
{
    /* Configuration Descriptor */

    0x09,                                               // Size of this descriptor in bytes
    USB_DESCRIPTOR_CONFIGURATION,                       // Descriptor Type
    67,0,                //(67 Bytes)Size of the Config descriptor.e
    2,                                               // Number of interfaces in this cfg
    0x01,                                               // Index value of this configuration
    0x00,                                               // Configuration string index
    USB_ATTRIBUTE_DEFAULT | USB_ATTRIBUTE_SELF_POWERED, // Attributes
    50,                                                 // Max power consumption (2X mA)

    /* Descriptor for Function 1 - CDC     */ 

    /* Interface Descriptor */

    0x09,                                           // Size of this descriptor in bytes
    USB_DESCRIPTOR_INTERFACE,                       // Descriptor Type
    0,                                           // Interface Number
    0x00,                                           // Alternate Setting Number
    0x01,                                           // Number of endpoints in this interface
    USB_CDC_COMMUNICATIONS_INTERFACE_CLASS_CODE,    // Class code
    USB_CDC_SUBCLASS_ABSTRACT_CONTROL_MODEL,        // Subclass code
    USB_CDC_PROTOCOL_AT_V250,                       // Protocol code
    0x00,                                           // Interface string index

    /* CDC Class-Specific Descriptors */

    sizeof(USB_CDC_HEADER_FUNCTIONAL_DESCRIPTOR),               // Size of the descriptor
    USB_CDC_DESC_CS_INTERFACE,                                  // CS_INTERFACE
    USB_CDC_FUNCTIONAL_HEADER,                                  // Type of functional descriptor
    0x20,0x01,                                                  // CDC spec version

    sizeof(USB_CDC_ACM_FUNCTIONAL_DESCRIPTOR),                  // Size of the descriptor
    USB_CDC_DESC_CS_INTERFACE,                                  // CS_INTERFACE
    USB_CDC_FUNCTIONAL_ABSTRACT_CONTROL_MANAGEMENT,             // Type of functional descriptor
    USB_CDC_ACM_SUPPORT_LINE_CODING_LINE_STATE_AND_NOTIFICATION,// bmCapabilities of ACM

    sizeof(USB_CDC_UNION_FUNCTIONAL_DESCRIPTOR_HEADER) + 1,     // Size of the descriptor
    USB_CDC_DESC_CS_INTERFACE,                                  // CS_INTERFACE
    USB_CDC_FUNCTIONAL_UNION,                                   // Type of functional descriptor
    0,                                                       // com interface number
    1,

    sizeof(USB_CDC_CALL_MANAGEMENT_DESCRIPTOR),                 // Size of the descriptor
    USB_CDC_DESC_CS_INTERFACE,                                  // CS_INTERFACE
    USB_CDC_FUNCTIONAL_CALL_MANAGEMENT,                         // Type of functional descriptor
    0x00,                                                       // bmCapabilities of CallManagement
    1,                                                       // Data interface number

    /* Interrupt Endpoint (IN)Descriptor */

    0x07,                           // Size of this descriptor
    USB_DESCRIPTOR_ENDPOINT,        // Endpoint Descriptor
    1| USB_EP_DIRECTION_IN,      // EndpointAddress ( EP1 IN INTERRUPT)
    USB_TRANSFER_TYPE_INTERRUPT,    // Attributes type of EP (INTERRUPT)
    0x10,0x00,                      // Max packet size of this EP
    0x02,                           // Interval (in ms)

    /* Interface Descriptor */

    0x09,                               // Size of this descriptor in bytes
    USB_DESCRIPTOR_INTERFACE,           // INTERFACE descriptor type
    1,      // Interface Number
    0x00,                               // Alternate Setting Number
    0x02,                               // Number of endpoints in this interface
    USB_CDC_DATA_INTERFACE_CLASS_CODE,  // Class code
    0x00,                               // Subclass code
    USB_CDC_PROTOCOL_NO_CLASS_SPECIFIC, // Protocol code
    0x00,                               // Interface string index

    /* Bulk Endpoint (OUT)Descriptor */

    0x07,                       // Size of this descriptor
    USB_DESCRIPTOR_ENDPOINT,    // Endpoint Descriptor
    2|USB_EP_DIRECTION_OUT,     // EndpointAddress ( EP2 OUT)
    USB_TRANSFER_TYPE_BULK,     // Attributes type of EP (BULK)
    0x00, 0x02,                 // Max packet size of this EP
    0x00,                       // Interval (in ms)

     /* Bulk Endpoint (IN)Descriptor */

    0x07,                       // Size of this descriptor
    USB_DESCRIPTOR_ENDPOINT,    // Endpoint Descriptor
    2|USB_EP_DIRECTION_IN,      // EndpointAddress ( EP2 IN )
    0x02,                       // Attributes type of EP (BULK)
    0x00, 0x02,                 // Max packet size of this EP
    0x00,                       // Interval (in ms)

};



/******************************************************
 * USB Driver Initialization
 ******************************************************/
const DRV_USBHS_INIT drvUSBInit =
{
    /* Interrupt Source for USB module */
    .interruptSource = INT_SOURCE_USB_1,

    /* Interrupt Source for USB module */
    .interruptSourceUSBDma = INT_SOURCE_USB_1_DMA,

    /* System module initialization */
    .moduleInit = {SYS_MODULE_POWER_RUN_FULL},

    .operationMode = DRV_USBHS_OPMODE_DEVICE,

    .operationSpeed = USB_SPEED_HIGH,

    /* Stop in idle */
    .stopInIdle = false,

    /* Suspend in sleep */
    .suspendInSleep = false,

    /* Identifies peripheral (PLIB-level) ID */
    .usbID = 0,
};
```